# how to find square root of a number by using babylonian method

Tags: fpga, verilog

how to find the square root of number by using babylonian method equation: Xn+1=1/2(Xn+(s/Xn))  by using verilog code any one help me ........I have written a code but its not synthesis not running.

```
module squre (
  input [15:0] a,
  output reg [15:0] x
);
  reg [15:0] b;
  reg [15:0] y [0:9];
  integer i;

  initial b=16'd1;

  always @(a) begin
    y[0]=b;
    for (i=0; i<10; i=i+1) begin
      y[i+1]= ((y[i]+(a/y[i]))/2);
      if (y[i+1]==y[i]) begin
        y[9]=y[i];
        i=9;
      end
    end
    x=y[9];
  end

endmodule
```

If any problem in program tell me fast. also in this program has to be dividing problem. Tell me how to write the program.

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please put your code in a code block using the {} button. Please use proper capitalisation of words in the title and question as this site uses Standard English. Please also remove "tell me fast". We'll tell you when we have time.

Comment: First thing : does it work correctly in simulation? There's no point going on to synthesis until it does, and you haven't posted your testbench.

Comment: You cannot change a loop count outside of the for loop incrementer if you want your code to synthesize.  You'll have to rewrite the code to remove the i=9.

Comment: We don't do *gimme da codz* here.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the only thing that prevents synthesis is the `if` statement inside the `for` loop. Without this, the code specifies a perfectly valid, if somewhat large and messy, combinatoral network.

That's assuming that your tools know how to implement the `/` operator as a combinatorial network in the first place.

Comment: write this code in structural form u synthsesis